# How many ways can we choose $6$ balls such that two pairs of chosen balls have the same number?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> Given $10$ white and $10$ black balls numbered $1, 2,..., 10$, how many ways can we choose $6$ balls such that two pairs of chosen balls have the same number?

WLOG I pick from white first. Case one, I choose four(the maximum of one colour) from white. There are ${10\choose4}$ ways to do so. I have ${4\choose3}$ ways to pair these with black, so ${10\choose4}\times{4\choose3}$. Case two, I choose three from white in ${10\choose3}$ ways, then ways to pair with black equals ${3\choose2}$, and since three pairs are allowed but two numbers from black are already taken, ${8\choose1}$ ways to choose the remaining black. Whence, ${10\choose3}\times{3\choose2}\times{8\choose1}$. Case three is completed in the same way as two.

Together, ${10\choose4}\times{4\choose2}+{10\choose3}\times{3\choose2}\times{8\choose1}+{10\choose2}\times{2\choose2}\times{8\choose2}=5400$

This answer is wrong. The correct is 5040, which is explained in a way I understand completely. Case two already results in more choices than this. Because of this, I am less interested in answers that solve this problem using other methods, and more interested in an answer that explains why my reasoning goes awry.

Comment: There is a mistake when you multiply by the number of black balls. For example, in the case 1, you should not multiply by $4*3$, but by ${4 \choose 2}$ : otherwise, you count two times the same pair of black balls.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you, this was definitely wrong on my part. I have corrected this in the post because the answer is still wrong and I think there is another less trivial error.

Comment: Given 10 white and 10 black balls numbered 1,2,...,10, how many ways can we choose 6 balls such that **ONLY?** two pairs of chosen balls have the same number?

Comment: I assume you meant to say $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pair these with black, giving $\binom{10}{4}\binom{4}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want **only** two pairs that match :

First, you choose the two numbers that will be in common for white and black : you have ${10 \choose 2}$ possibilities. Then, you have two choose the two remaining balls among the $16$ left. You have ${16 \choose 2}$ possibilities, but you have to exclude the $8$ cases where you pick again two balls with the same number.

So the final result is
$${10 \choose 2} \times \left({16 \choose 2} - 8 \right) = 5040$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since those $\binom{16}{2}$ choices may include choices in which the two balls display the same number.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes true, but the question doesnt say (ONLY)...i have commented on the question's OP regarding that

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for pointing that, I edited. I hope this is correct now.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  Nice save.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi  The answer $5400$ would still be incorrect even if we allowed for three pairs of matching numbers, of which there are $\binom{10}{3}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It would be if you pick objects in stages, i.e. if you have to select 2 objects from a set of 10, (a) one by one (b) together, the answers would differ by a factor of 2

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi  I am not clear on what you are trying to count, or why you wish to pick objects in stages.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I was falsifying your statement "The answer 5400 would still be incorrect even if we allowed for three pairs"

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi  The original answer $\binom{10}{2}\binom{16}{2}$ counts each case in which there are three pairs three times, once for each way of designating two of those pairs as the two required pairs.  Exactly two pairs:  Choose two of the ten numbers for the pairs of balls, choose two of the remaining eight numbers from which one color is drawn, choose one of the two colors for each of those numbers, which gives $\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}2^2 = 5040$.  Exactly three pairs:  Choose which three of the ten numbers are used for the pairs in $\binom{10}{3} = 120$ ways.  Add to obtain $5160$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig choose 2 pairs of alike, i.e. use ${10}\choose{2}$ then from the remaining 16 items, choose 2 again without a restriction. What you're doing by $10 \choose 3$ is choosing a set of 3 balls from the white or the black container (whichever you considered reference), and choosing 3 balls again but with complete dependence on this first. Whereas, what I am doing to get 5400 is, choose 2 pairs and count selections of 2 from the remaining. Also, the addition you did to get 5160 is not justified.... you're forcefully adding 2 different things

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi  For exactly three pairs, I selected the three numbers which appear on both a black and a white ball, which completely determines the three pairs.  I added the cases of exactly two pairs and exactly three pairs since we add when we cannot do two tasks at the same time.  This is the [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum).

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi You made a common error in combinatorics by designating two of the pairs as the designated two pairs, which counts each case in which there are three pairs $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ times, once for each way you could designate two of those three pairs as your pairs.  If you dispute this, I suggest you ask the question "Given $10$ white and $10$ black balls numbered $1, 2, \ldots, 10$, how many ways can we choose $6$ balls such that *at least* two pairs of balls have the same number?"  and include your proposed solution.  Place a link to this question for additional context.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you're not on the same page as I am. The thing is you're choosing everything in one go, whereas I am treating AB,C and AC,B as distinct. You're correct in your words but you haven't looked at my point.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi  As I said, please pose the question I suggested in my preceding comment, include your proposed solution, and include a link to this question.  Your question should be well-received.  Moreover, it is the best way for you to get feedback on your proposed solution.  I will not respond to any further comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the problems. They are listed below:

Case 1: There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pair the white balls with black. So, we have this as $\binom{10}{4}\binom{4}{2} = 1260$ ways.

```
Case 1 should be repeated twice. Once as white, once as black.
```

Case 2: Choose 3 from white to get $\binom{10}{3}$ ways and then pair with black in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways. Now, as the last black should b=not be paired, you have $\binom{7}{1}$ ways which correspond to a total of $\binom{10}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{1} = 2520$ ways.

This makes the total as $2*\text{Case1 + Case2}=1260*2+2520=5040$ ways